# How to search multiple search patterns from a file with grep

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression, search

If I search for multiple search strings in `grep` : usually just do:

```
grep "search1\|search2" somefolder/*.txt
```

but, what if I have 100 or more search strings? Can I say like this:

```
grep "stringPattern.txt" somefolder/*.txt
```

where `stringPattern.txt` is a file containing a list of words I need to search in `*.txt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` has the `-f` flag exactly for this, use:

```
grep -f patternfile somefolder/*.txt
```

Where in the `patternfile` the search patterns are separated line by line.

Answer (score 1):

you can also work with other way around. if you have 100 patterns to search, then make a list what you don't want to search if it is less than 100 patterns and make it in a file1.txt

```
grep -vf file1.txt somefolder/*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used perl to do this, as you can use perl to build a regex from an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
open ( my $searchfile, '<', "searchfile.txt" ) or die $!; 

my @search_for = <$searchfile>; 
close ( $searchfile );

my $search_regex = join ( "|", map {quotemeta} @search_for ); 
   $search_regex = qr/$search_regex/; 

print "Regex: $search_regex\n"; 

foreach my $file ( glob ( "somefolder/*.txt" ) ) { 
    open ( my $check, '<', $file ) or die $!; 
    while ( <$check> ) {
        print if m/$search_regex/;
    }
    close ( $check );
}
```

Note - `quotemeta` will escape metacharacters, which is good if you want to search for things including backslashes, spaces etc. But bad if you want to specify regex patterns.